# Implementing append and insertAt functions in Doubly Linked List Data Structures class lab project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have been working on this project for a week, but can't seem to make this project get the expected output I need to pass this lab. The following is the scaffold for the two functions mentioned in this post:

lab04.cpp (blank scaffolding with pre and post conditions):

```
#include <ostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "linkedlistd.h"

namespace DS {

//     Precondition: cursor is not NULL
//     Postcondition: A new node is created with the datum of newdatum.
//      The new node next points to cursor->next
//      The new node prev points to cursor
//      The cursor->next prev points to the new node
//      The cursor next points to the new node
//      Returns a pointer to the new node
linkedList::node* linkedList::appendAt (const value_type& newdatum,node* cursor) {


}

//     Precondition: none
//     Postcondition: A new node is created with the datum of newdatum.
//      The new node next points to cursor
//      The new node prev points to cursor->prev
//      The cursor->prev next points to the new node
//      The cursor prev points to the new node
//      Returns a pointer to the new node
linkedList::node* linkedList::insertAt (const value_type& newdatum,node* cursor) {

}
} // end namespace
```

The following code is my version of the file that includes my attempt at trying to solve these two functions:

```
#include "linkedlistd.h"

namespace DS {

    //     Precondition: cursor is not NULL
    //     Postcondition: A new node is created with the datum of newdatum.
    //      The new node next points to cursor->next
    //      The new node prev points to cursor
    //      The cursor->next prev points to the new node
    //      The cursor next points to the new node
    //      Returns a pointer to the new node
    linkedList::node* linkedList::appendAt(const value_type& newdatum, node* cursor) {
        node* new_node = new node();
        if (cursor->next() != nullptr) {
            node* next_node = cursor->next();
            new_node->setData(newdatum);
            cursor->setNext(new_node);
            new_node->setPrev(cursor);
            new_node->setNext(next_node);
            next_node->setPrev(new_node);
            return next_node;
        }
        else {
            new_node->setPrev(cursor);
            cursor->setNext(new_node);
            new_node->setNext(nullptr);
            return new_node;
        }
    }

    //     Precondition: none
    //     Postcondition: A new node is created with the datum of newdatum.
    //      The new node next points to cursor
    //      The new node prev points to cursor->prev
    //      The cursor->prev next points to the new node
    //      The cursor prev points to the new node
    //      Returns a pointer to the new node
    linkedList::node* linkedList::insertAt(const value_type& newdatum, node* cursor) {
        node* new_node = new node(newdatum);

        if (cursor == nullptr) {
            tail->setPrev(new_node);
            new_node->setNext(tail);
            new_node->setPrev(tail->prev());
            return new_node;
        }

        if (cursor == head) {
            new_node->setNext(head);
            head->setPrev(new_node);
            head = new_node;
            return new_node;
        }
        new_node->setNext(cursor);
        new_node->setPrev(cursor->prev());
        cursor->prev()->setNext(new_node);
        cursor->setPrev(cursor);
        return new_node;
    }
} // end namespace
```

But when I run the project, I get no output.

The output I am supposed to get is:

```
->[5]->[10]->[20]--X

X--[20]<-[10]<-[5]<-

--X

->[30]->[5]->[10]->[20]->[7]->[2]--X

X--[2]<-[7]<-[20]<-[10]<-[5]<-[30]<-

->[1]->[2]->[4]->[8]->[16]->[32]->[16]->[8]->[4]->[2]->[1]--X

X--[1]<-[2]<-[4]<-[8]<-[16]<-[32]<-[16]<-[8]<-[4]<-[2]<-[1]<-
```

Please help me finish this project, as my understanding of doubly linked lists and passing this class depends on it. Please respond with the correct implementation for these two functions with an explanation why you coded what you did to solve the problem. The project files for the lab are included in their entirety below. Thanks so much for helping me in advance, and I look forward to reading your responses.

linkedlistd.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDDLIST_H
#define LINKEDDLIST_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "node_dll.h"

namespace DS {

    class linkedList
    {
    public:
        typedef int value_type;
        typedef DSDLL::node<value_type> node;
        linkedList();
        virtual ~linkedList();

        node* appendAt(const value_type&, node*);
        node* insertAt(const value_type&, node* = nullptr);
        void insertItem(value_type);
        void makeList(const value_type[], const size_t& count);
        void deleteList();

        //The following two assessors are for testing purpose and implemented inline
        //Therefore, you do not need to implement in the cpp file
        node* getHead() { return head; };
        node* getTail() { return tail; };

        //The following friend function is implemented in lablinklist.cpp
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const linkedList&);
        friend std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream&, const linkedList&);
    private:
        node* head;
        node* tail;
    };

} //end namespace

#endif /* linkedList_H_ */
```

node_dll.h

```
#ifndef NODE_DLL_H_
#define NODE_DLL_H_

namespace DSDLL {

    template <typename T>
    class node
    {
    public:
        typedef T value_type;
        node(value_type d = value_type(), node* n = nullptr, node* p = nullptr) : data_field(d), next_ptr(n), prev_ptr(p) {}

        //Assessor/Getters
        const value_type& getData() const { return data_field; }
        node const* getPrev() const { return prev_ptr; }
        node const* getNext() const { return next_ptr; }

        //Mutators/Setters
        void setData(const value_type& d) { data_field = d; }
        void setPrev(node* new_link) { prev_ptr = new_link; }
        void setNext(node* new_link) { next_ptr = new_link; }

        //Other
        value_type& data() { return data_field; }
        node*& prev() { return prev_ptr; }
        node*& next() { return next_ptr; }

    private:
        value_type data_field;
        node* next_ptr;
        node* prev_ptr;
    };

} /* namespace DSDLL */

#endif /* NODE_DLL_H_ */
```

lablinklist.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlistd.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace DS;


int main() {

    linkedList list1;
    linkedList::node* tn1, * tn2;

    //Test of adding items out of order

    list1.insertItem(5);
    list1.insertItem(20);
    list1.insertItem(10);
    cout << list1 << endl;
    cout >> list1 << endl;

    //Test of deleting entire list
    list1.deleteList();
    cout << list1 << endl;

    //Add items again using insertAt and appendAt
    list1.insertAt(5);
    tn1 = list1.appendAt(10, list1.getHead());
    tn2 = list1.appendAt(7, list1.getTail());
    list1.appendAt(20, tn1);
    list1.insertAt(30, list1.getHead());
    list1.appendAt(2, tn2);
    //Output forwards
    cout << list1 << endl;
    //Output reverse
    cout >> list1 << endl;

    //Now replace list with a new one in a specific order
    int pow2[] = { 1,2,4,8,16,32,16,8,4,2,1 };
    list1.makeList(pow2, sizeof(pow2) / sizeof(int));
    cout << list1 << endl;
    cout >> list1 << endl;

    //Returning a non-zero number, if not 3, then we know it seg-faulted
    return 3;
}

namespace DS {

    /*

    The following is provided so that everybody can easily get the same exact output

    */
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const linkedList& srcList) {

        //Set a current-pointer to the "head".
        const linkedList::node* cursor = srcList.head;

        //While current-pointer is not NULL
        while (cursor != nullptr)
        {
            //Print the data member ("datum") of the current node
            os << "->[" << cursor->getData() << "]";
            //Set the current-pointer to the "next" node in the list.
            cursor = cursor->getNext();
        }
        //Print out a basic termination symbol
        std::cout << "--X" << std::endl;

        return os;
    }

    std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& os, const linkedList& srcList) {

        //Set a current-pointer to the "head".
        const linkedList::node* cursor = srcList.tail;
        if (cursor == nullptr)
            return os;

        //Print out a start symbol
        os << "X--[" << cursor->getData() << "]";
        cursor = cursor->getPrev();

        //While current-pointer is not NULL
        while (cursor != nullptr)
        {
            //Print the data member ("datum") of the current node
            os << "<-[" << cursor->getData() << "]";
            //Set the current-pointer to the "next" node in the list.
            cursor = cursor->getPrev();
        }
        //Print out a basic termination symbol
        std::cout << "<-" << std::endl;

        return os;
    }
}
```

linkedlistd.cpp

```
#include <ostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "linkedlistd.h"

namespace DS {

    linkedList::linkedList() {
        head = tail = nullptr;
    }

    linkedList::~linkedList() {
        deleteList();
    }

    void linkedList::insertItem(value_type newdatum) {

        node* ccursor = head;
        node* pcursor = nullptr;

        if (head == NULL) {
            insertAt(newdatum, ccursor);
        }
        else {
            while (ccursor != NULL && newdatum > ccursor->getData()) {
                pcursor = ccursor;
                ccursor = ccursor->next();
            }

            appendAt(newdatum, pcursor);
        }

    }

    void linkedList::makeList(const value_type items[], const size_t& count) {

        deleteList();

        if (count == 0) return;

        insertAt(items[0]);

        node* ccursor = head;

        for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
            ccursor = appendAt(items[i], ccursor);
        }

    }

    void linkedList::deleteList() {

        node* dcursor;

        while (head != nullptr) {
            dcursor = head;
            head = head->next();
            delete dcursor;
        }
        head = tail = nullptr;

    }

} //end of DS namespace
```

Comment: Change your main to only insert one element and print the list. Run your program in your debugger. Set a breakpoint for the insertion routine. Step through the insertion routine and make sure the element is being inserted. After inserting the element, inspect your list in your debugger. Make sure the element is still in there. Set a breakpoint for your print functionality. Do the same thing as above. When you figure out whether your issue is insertion or printing, edit your question to be a [example].

Comment: You can narrow down the problem with your debugger.

Comment: Draw pictures. I kid you not. Draw the list. Draw each step required to perform a single task, insert, remove, whatever. See what you are doing as you are doing it and make sure what you are doing makes sense. Use the pictures as the basis for your code and as the expected when you are debugging the code. When debugging, follow your coded instructions to the letter and try to draw the list. When you find yourself deviating from the pictures you drew earlier, you found a bug and probably know what you needed to do instead.

Comment: You may also want to separate this into several super small functions, it will allow you to create a more simplified code, with better readability (even for **you** it will be easier to read). You can also use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), as silly as it sounds, it really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your following code statements are incorrect:

```
if (cursor == nullptr) {
    tail->setPrev(new_node);
    new_node->setNext(tail);
    new_node->setPrev(tail->prev());
    return new_node;
}

    ...
    new_node->setNext(cursor);
    new_node->setPrev(cursor->prev());
    cursor->prev()->setNext(new_node);
    cursor->setPrev(cursor);
    return new_node;
```

See below for corrections.

**Case 1:** When cursor is `nullptr`, that is the `new_node` must be inserted at 'last' as no matching location was found somewhere in middle. This assumes 'tail' is your last element (which should be as per naming convention):

```
if (cursor == nullptr){
    tail->setNext(new_node);
    new_node->setPrev(tail);
    tail = new_node;
    return new_node;
}
```

**Case 2:** When cursor points to somewhere in middle. It is not NULL. `new_node` is added just before `cursor`.

```
...
new_node->setNext(cursor);
new_node->setPrev(cursor->prev());
cursor->prev()->setNext(new_node);
cursor->setPrev(new_node);
return new_node;
```